# Two clicks required when only one should be needed on iPad/iPhone

Tags: html, mobile, safari, click, jquery-address

I'm working on a site which is supposed to support both mobile and desktop devices.  I'm using [jquery-address plugin](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) to make an image gallery which can use hash tags to be deep linkable.

But I'm noticing a problem in ipad simulator with iOS5 and iphone 5 where I have to click a category within the image gallery twice on the image gallery to get the event to work properly.  It works fine on chrome/safari/firefox on OSX with one click.

So far I've only seen this on iphone/ipad.  **Any ideas about why desktop browsers work fine with one click, but iOS on ipad/iphone need two?**  I'm at a loss here.  I can't tell if the problem is with my markup/javascript or an obscure bug in jquery-address/safari on iPad/iPhone.

Comment: Tried it on an iPad without JS : same problem. So it's the way Safari Mobile handles #. I would try with absolute url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is due to your markup and having a hover state on .gallery-category:

```
.gallery-category:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

iOS doesn't support :hover in the normal way because there's no way to detect a hover state without a mouse. It usually sorts itself out on straight up a:hover states, but I'm guessing because your markup is a bit complicated (and there's a :hover state on the parent) it's causing it to break.

I think if you replace the above snippet to work on

```
.gallery-category a:hover {...
```

it will fix it (I haven't tried it on your code though)

Comment: I'll give it a shot later today.

Comment: Thanks for heading me in the right direction. It turned out that I had a `mouseleave` event handler that was making me double-tap on an iPad when I wanted a single-tap action.